# ExpandableListview - Update UI of Group view while clicking on the child items

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I was integrated expandable list view in my app. I have two problems here.

1. I am trying to update the UI of Group view label while clicking on the Child view Item. But here my problem is I am unable to access group view Label in getChildView() method.
2. How to make some child items are single choice and some other are Multichoice Listview.

I tried a lot but I am unable to find out. please can anyone help me.

```
Code
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        final Button btnListChild = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnAttributeListItem);
        btnListChild.setText(childText);
        btnListChild.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                btnListChild
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.attributes_custom_selected_button);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lbAttributeHeader);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is an old question but I have a similar problem to No.1 mentioned above.  I wanted to have a count of how many items where selected in the child shown on the group header.  So when the  users clicks on the child Checkbox (onCheckedChanged) I updated my model, and call notifyDataSetChanged which then calls getGroupView again where I update the label with a count of how many items are checked.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Can you add some code for this @SammyT